# Http Live Streaming not working on Apache

Tags: apache, mime-types, http-live-streaming

My Http Live Streaming setup: Apache hosts the html, m3u8, and ts files

The **ts** files are copied over from http:devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/fileSequence*.ts. There is nothing wrong with the video encoding (verified by actually playing these files)

**m3u8** files (both the multi-bitrate and leaf-level) are copied over from apple's example and are syntactically correct, as follows:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXT-X-MEDIA-SEQUENCE:0
#EXTINF:10, no desc
fileSequence0.ts
...
#EXTINF:1, no desc
fileSequence180.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

**videoplay.html** (below) fails to stream the video from my apache server

```
<video src="bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8" controls autoplay ></video>
```

However on modifying videoplay.html (below), the video streams just fine from Apple's website

```
<video src="http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8" controls autoplay ></video>
```

I suspected something wrong with mime type settings because Chrome was handling http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 and http://localhost/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8 differently. While Chrome tries to play the former, it downloads and saves the latter one. So I double checked my mime type setting, which is set as below in my httpd.conf

```
AddType application/x-mpegURL .m3u8
AddType video/MP2T .ts
```

- Is my mime type setting correct?
- How do we figure the mime type association advertised by apple's website?
- Or do we have to look elsewhere to fix this?

Comment: i have same problem but i can't solve it with deleting the empty lines of index file

Comment: see that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11986313/http-live-streaming-for-iphone-and-why-we-use-m3u8-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might seem strange but I also faced similar problems, and after much debugging I found that empty lines in the .m3u8 index file can cause such issues. Please double check for empty lines in your index file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the HLS rfc documentation you should use "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" or "audio/mpegurl" but you could also simply make the path end with .m3u8 or .m3u.

> Each Playlist file MUST be identifiable either by the path
>   component    of its URI or by HTTP Content-Type.  In the first case,
>   the path MUST    end with either .m3u8 or .m3u.  In the second, the
>   HTTP Content-Type    MUST be "application/vnd.apple.mpegurl" or
>   "audio/mpegurl".  Clients    SHOULD refuse to parse Playlists that are
>   not so identified.

~ Chapter 4 of rfc8216, HTTP Live Streaming

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but for clarity's sake:

```
File extension |                 MIME type
-------------------------------------------------------------
.M3U8          | application/x-mpegURL (or vnd.apple.mpegURL)
.ts            | video/MP2T
```

Source: [Apple Developer Streaming Media Guide – HTTP Streaming Architecture](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/HTTPStreamingArchitecture/HTTPStreamingArchitecture.html)