# HTTP Live Streaming from Apache on Windows

Tags: ios, http-live-streaming

I have a small iPhone app that consumes streaming video. With Apache on my Macbook, I have been able to get it working without any trouble. i.e., I've deployed the .m3u8 and .ts files and the server is correctly streaming the files and the phone app is displaying the video too.

Now I try to replicate this on an apache server running on a Windows Server, and can't get it to work. I've got the correct settings in mime.types for both content types.

Using the mediastreamvalidator locally returns verified ok status. Running it on the remote stream hangs it.

access.log shows the first five segments being requested and then nothing. If I try to access from Safari it shows the controls and the trackbar updates up to 8 seconds and then nothing. I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438680/http-live-streaming-not-working-on-apache) question but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

In the browser, the GET statements for both local and remote return identical results.

Safari plays from the local URL, Firefox and Chrome don't and neither gives any errors.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Turns out you need to use the "-no-floating-point-duration" and "-iframe-index-file none" parameters to mediafilesegmenter.

Still doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome. But that's not a problem for now.

Comment: Does the Windows Server mean you were running Apache on a Windows machine? Do the Apple HTTP Live Streaming tools work on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you need to use the "-no-floating-point-duration" and "-iframe-index-file none" parameters to mediafilesegmenter. Still doesn't work in Firefox or Chrome. But that's not a problem for now.