# Playing m3u8 Files with HTML Video Tag

Tags: html, streaming, html5-video, http-live-streaming, m3u8

I am trying to use HTTP Live Streaming (HLS) to stream video to my computers and my iPhone.  After reading through the Apple 'HTTP Live Streaming Overview' as well as 'Best Practices for Creating and Deploying HTTP Live Streaming Media for the iPhone and iPad', I am a bit stuck.

I took my source file (an mkv) and used ffmpeg to encode the file the MPEG-TS format and Apple-recommended settings and a Baseline 3.0 profile:

```
ffmpeg -i "example.mkv" -f mpegts -threads:v 4 -sws_flags bicubic -vf "scale=640:352,setdar=16/9,ass=sub.ass" -codec:v libx264 -r 29.970 -b:v 1200k -profile:v baseline -level:v 3.0 -movflags faststart -coder 1 -flags +loop -cmp chroma -partitions +parti8x8+parti4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 6 -me_range 16 -g 239 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -b_strategy 1 -qcomp 0.6 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -direct-pred 1 -fast-pskip 1 -af "aresample=48000" -codec:a libvo_aacenc -b:a 96k -ac 2  -y "output.ts"
```

No worries there.  I used a [pre-compiled segmenting tool](https://code.google.com/p/httpsegmenter/) to segment the video and build a .m3u8 playlist.  The resultant file looked like this:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-TARGETDURATION:10
#EXTINF:10,
http://localhost/media/stream/stream-1.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://localhost/media/stream/stream-2.ts
#EXTINF:10,
http://localhost/media/stream/stream-3.ts
#EXT-X-ENDLIST
```

I checked that against some [Example Playlist Files for use with HTTP Live Streaming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2288/_index.html), and I don't see any issues.  I also tried playing the .m3u8 file in VLC, and it works like a charm.

I created an HTML page to play the file:

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset=utf-8/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='player'>
            <video width="352" height="288" src="stream.m3u8" controls autoplay>
            </video>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this page does not work in Chrome, Safari, on my iPhone.  The html5 video tag examples on w3schools work fine on my computer, and the official Apple overview mentioned above gives an HTML example very similar to my page.  Nevertheless, my video player is completely unresponsive when I visit my own .m3u8 page.

Comment: Can you show the output of the mediastreamvalidator tool?

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Unfortunately, I haven't forked over the cash to be a "real" Apple developer, so I don't have that particular tool.  I've been looking for a likely substitute with little success.  Any advice you could give on that front would be welcome!

Comment: Maybe you could put the files on a public webserver. You can use a micro Amazon EC2 instance if you need a free webserver. Then someone with access to more tools could take a look.

Actually, that makes me wonder about the mime types being returned by your webserver... See if this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438680/http-live-streaming-not-working-on-apache/15696465

Comment: Have you tried browsing directly to the m3u8 on your safari, and not via the html? for example, if your m3u8 file exists on the server under http://myserver/mymoviue.m3u8, then browsing here should display the video. If this doesn't work, then your problem isn't in the HTML.

Comment: HLS is still not supported natively by Windows desktop Chrome https://caniuse.com/#search=hls but just worked on my old iPhone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hls video streaming on iOS/Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43287226/hls-video-streaming-on-ios-safari)

Answer (score 73):

Might be a little late with the answer but you need to supply the MIME type attribute in the video tag: type="application/x-mpegURL". The video tag I use for a 16:9 stream looks like this.

```
<video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

Comment: If anyone else has tested this answer, It should be noted that It won't work on Chrome. Works fine in Edge. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23388308/4092887) for more information about a solution for browser compatibility.

Comment: HLS won't stream in a page on Chrome in just a video tag, as it is not the native browser for HLS.

Comment: It's not playing in edge for me. perhaps its because i am using `video-react` package

Answer (score 48):

You can use **video js** library for easily play **HLS video's**.
It allows to directly play videos

```
<!-- CSS  -->
 <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">


<!-- HTML -->
<video id='hls-example'  class="video-js vjs-default-skin" width="400" height="300" controls>
<source type="application/x-mpegURL" src="http://www.streambox.fr/playlists/test_001/stream.m3u8">
</video>


<!-- JS code -->
<!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/ie8-version/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/videojs-contrib-hls/5.14.1/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
<script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.2.3/video.js"></script>

<script>
var player = videojs('hls-example');
player.play();
</script>
```

[GitHub Video Js](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls#cdn)

Comment: videojs wouldn't play my encrypted HLS video on iOS

Comment: video.js has been rewritten: https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming Backwards compatible with HLS and Dash, supports encryption as well.

Answer (score 18):

The standard html5 video player supports mp4, WebM, 3gp and OGV format directly.

```html
    <video controls>
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.webm type=video/webm>
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.ogv type=video/ogg>
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4 type=video/mp4>
      <source src=http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.3gp type=video/3gp>
    </video>
```

We can add an external HLS js script in web application.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Your title</title>
      
    
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
      <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
      data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="https://cdn3.wowza.com/1/ejBGVnFIOW9yNlZv/cithRSsv/hls/live/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      </video>
      
    <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
    player.play();
    </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 10):

```
<html>
<body>
    <video width="600" height="400" controls>
        <source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
    </video>
</body>
```

Stream HLS or m3u8 files using above code.
it works for desktop: **ms edge** browser (not working with desktop chrome)
and
mobile: **chrome,opera mini** browser.

To play on all browser use flash based media player.
[media player to support all browser](https://www.momovi.com/opensource/momovi-video-hls)

Comment: if you want to play direct .m3u8 (HLS file), then add **chrome** extension called **Native HLS Playback** from chrome web app.

Comment: This solution doesn't work. I tried it on Firefox and Chrome. Even installing **Native HLS Playback** doesn't do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

Adding to ben.bourdin answer, you can at least in any HTML based application, check if the browser supports HLS in its video element:

Let´s assume that your video element ID is "myVideo", then through javascript you can use the "canPlayType" function (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_canplaytype.asp)

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myVideo");
if(videoElement.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl') === "probably" || videoElement.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl') === "maybe"){
    //Actions like playing the .m3u8 content
}
else{
    //Actions like playing another video type
}
```

The canPlayType function, returns:

"" when there is no support for the specified audio/video type

"maybe" when the browser might support the specified audio/video type

"probably" when it most likely supports the specified audio/video type (you can use just this value in the validation to be more sure that your browser supports the specified type)

Hope this help :)

Best regards!

Answer (score 6):

Use Flowplayer:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.4/commercial/skin/skin.css">
    <style>

   </style>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/7.0.4/commercial/flowplayer.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//releases.flowplayer.org/hlsjs/flowplayer.hlsjs.min.js"></script> 
  <script>
  flowplayer(function (api) {
    api.on("load", function (e, api, video) {
      $("#vinfo").text(api.engine.engineName + " engine playing " + video.type);
    }); });
  </script>

<div class="flowplayer fixed-controls no-toggle no-time play-button obj"
      style="    width: 85.5%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 7.2%;
    margin-top: 6%;
    z-index: 1000;" data-key="$812975748999788" data-live="true" data-share="false" data-ratio="0.5625"  data-logo="">
      <video autoplay="true" stretch="true">

         <source type="application/x-mpegurl" src="http://live.wmncdn.net/safaritv2/live2.stream/index.m3u8">
      </video>   
   </div>
```

Different methods are available in flowplayer.org website.

Comment: what is `api` here?

Comment: Nothing is being displayed with above. Why? Commenting out `<script> flowplayer(function(api) {...`  displays media player sceen in browser. Why? Something went wrong withing script tag? Can anybody help here?

Answer (score 0):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Index file</title>
    <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script defer src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.20.3/video.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <video
      id="my-video"
      class="video-js"
      controls
      preload="auto"
      width="640"
      height="264"
      controls
      data-setup="{}"
    >
      <source
        src="https://live-par-2-cdn-alt.livepush.io/live/bigbuckbunnyclip/index.m3u8"
        type="application/x-mpegURL"
      />
    </video>

  </body>
</html>
```

**this is a working code**