Using FFMPEG and PHP to encode HLS video on the fly
I'm re-encoding a MP4 video to HLS using FFMPEG with PHP. I'm trying to then directly serve to the output to a HTML page's <video> tag. The following script (encode.php) encodes the video as I require and it works if I use the script url directly in VLC player for example but I'm struggling to get the gtml page to play it. The resulting video file should be compatible with most browsers. I use video.src = 'encode.php' on my player html page.
Any help appreciated.
<?php

$input_video = 'whatever.mp4';

// video passthrough
// hls format
// audio (english strems only) to aac (6 channel)
// output to stdout

$ffmpeg_command = 'ffmpeg -i ' . escapeshellarg($input_video) . ' -map 0:v -c:v copy -map 0:a:m:language:eng -c:a aac -ac 6 -b:a 320k -f hls -hls_time 30 -hls_list_size 120 -start_number 0 -';

$handle = popen($ffmpeg_command, 'rb');

header('Content-Type: application/vnd.apple.mpegurl');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="output.m3u8"');

// stream the output to the browser
fpassthru($handle);
pclose($handle);
?>


Your script is apparently not returning a video, but a playlist.

shouldn’t the html video (I’m using videoJs) be able to open that ?

You still need to assign the playlist URL to a source element, and not the video element itself - https://stackoverflow.com/a/57368395/1427878

Thanks, that's actually how I had it, I've tried the player html in a few different ways but it never plays the video.
<video id="player"class='video-js vjs-default-skin' controls preload="auto" data-setup='{}'>     <source src="test_hls.php" type="application/x-mpegURL"> </video>

Does an individual video from the playlist play, when you assign it as a video source directly?

yes, in fact if I output to output.m3u8 for example instead of stdout, and use that as a source it plays, so i feel the issue is related to how the output is passed (headers etc) from the php file

Not sure why there would be any Content-Disposition header to begin with, try and remove that. And maybe try application/x-mpegURL instead of the current Content-Type.

Thanks, I had tried this already and a bunch of other header options, having no luck.

You comment:

yes, in fact if I output to output.m3u8 for example instead of stdout, and use that as a source it plays, ...

You may test if the <source> element (browser) is extension aware and rejects .php for some reason?
Workaround to impersonate a output.m3u8 file

Place a .htaccess file in docroot:

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^target/stuff/output.m3u8$ redir/encode.php [NC,L]


Place encode.php to DOCROOT/redir/encode.php
Test YOURDOMAIN/target/stuff/output.m3u8 in new browser window, redirection should succeed.
Test if you can use /target/stuff/output.m3u8 in the <source>, same as you tested successfully before

hope this helps to debug the issue.
