# Audio & Video not running on browser desktop

Tags: javascript, html

I have the video and sound with format "m3u8", it works and can play in mobile browser but it's not running on desktop browser (Chrome, edge)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to play html5 video play m3U8 on mobile and desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23388135/how-to-play-html5-video-play-m3u8-on-mobile-and-desktop)

Comment: @edo9k i try it but it's not work