# How to play MPEG-TS in chrome

Tags: video, h.264, vlc, aac, mpeg

I have a video in which I want to show the user ( 'the' user because he can access Chrome PC or Chrome android).

If it's possible it would have nice to use html5  tags, but since it TS it can't...

So, I need a better suggest on how could I play them rather then open vlc and copy&past the file path.
But that's terrible idea...

I saw [this](https://github.com/stefansundin/vlc-protocol) library which add VLC protocol ( vlc:// links ), but I prefer to use server side solutions.

I uploaded an example file in which you could see [here](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/raw-attachment/ticket/18714/3.mp4).

I don't want to convert all the files into another format.

Edit:
If someone comes here in future, after take @szatmary advice, there are some projects on GitHub who do it, however I can't use any of them without partially convert ( in a manner ), and since i'm working with extremely big files (10G+) and extremely weak computer ( Single 1.8 Cpu core ) I manage to display the audio only, not a real solution, but covers my needs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Convert the file to mp4. If the ts file is h.264+aac, you can convert to fmp4 in javascript and play via media source extensions, but that is A LOT of code to get working.

Answer (score 3):

You can play the `ts` directly with index `m3u8` file, if not you can make the `m3u8` file, which is just the index of the `ts` file.

Some browser like edge you directly play `ts`. Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23225645/6521116)

```
<video width="352" height="198" controls>
    <source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

For other browser like firefox and chrome, you need to feed the ts to video with js something like `video.js`,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>videojs-contrib-hls embed</title>

  <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  <h1>Video.js Example Embed</h1>

  <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="268" 
  data-setup='{}'>
    <source src="index.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
  </video>

  <script>
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Apart from** playing the `ts` file, you also can convert it to mp4.

You can use [pipe these ts files in to ffmpeg](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45899585/6521116) and output the mp4 file.

`cat *.ts | ffmpeg  -i pipe: -c:a copy -c:v copy output.mp4`

or If you ts file name not have order,

`grep .*.ts index.m3u8 | xargs cat | ffmpeg  -i pipe: -c:a copy -c:v copy output.mp4`

Comment: Chrome doesn't support mpeg-ts even if you install a plugin. mpeg4 works fine, but for mpeg-ts (aka mpeg2) the code you've provided just show a rotating circle

Answer (score 0):

I've tried all described solutions and found out that Chrome doesn't support mpeg-ts, with HPL Player plugin or without it. All solutions support mpeg4 only. Too bad, given that converting a stream from mpeg2 to mpeg4 by ffmpeg consumes 98% of my CPU, while using '-v copy' option takes not more than 4%.

Safari does support mpeg2 natively without any plugins though, e.g. this js works fine:

```
<body>
  <video width="640" height="480" controls autoplay
         src="http://<streaming-server>:port/path-to-index.m3u8">
  </video>
</body>
```