# Pipe input in to ffmpeg stdin

Tags: ffmpeg, pipe

I am trying to use ffmpeg to decode audio data. While it works to load from a file, I would like to avoid using files because to do so, means I would have to use a temporary. Instead, I'd like to pipe in the data(which I've previously loaded) using stdin.

Is this possible?

e.g.,

1. Manually load mp3 file
2. Pipe it in to the ffmpeg spawned process
3. Get raw output

(it should work with ffprobe and ffplay also)

Answer (score 41):

ffmpeg has a special pipe flag that instructs the program to consume stdin.
note that almost always the input format needs to be defined explicitly.

example (output is in PCM signed 16-bit little-endian format):

```
cat file.mp3 | ffmpeg -f mp3 -i pipe: -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le pipe:
```

pipe docs are [here](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe)
supported audio types are [here](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/audio%20types)

Comment: Can the output of an ffmpeg command be piped as input to a subsequent ffmpeg command? I'm having trouble figuring out if it can be.

Comment: yes you can! `ffmpeg -i file.mp3  -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le pipe: | ffmpeg -f mp3 -i pipe: -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le encoded.mp3`

Comment: ```Unable to find a suitable output format for 'cat'```

Comment: What is the exact command you are using and on which platform?

Comment: On Windows, `-i pipe:0` seems to work for input piped in

Answer (score 13):

**`-` is the same as `pipe:`**

I couldn't find where it's documented, and I don't have the patience to check the source, but `-` appears to be the exact same as `pipe:` according to my tests with ffmpeg 4.2.4, where `pipe:` does what you usually expect from `-` in other Linux utilities as mentioned [in the documentation of the pipe protocol](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-protocols.html#pipe):

> If number is not specified, by default the stdout file descriptor will be used for writing, stdin for reading.

So for example you could rewrite the command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45902691/895245

```
ffmpeg -f mp3 -i pipe: -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le pipe: < file.mp3
```

a bit more simply as:

```
ffmpeg -f mp3 -i - -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le - < file.mp3
```

Related: [What does "dash" - mean as ffmpeg output filename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596219/what-does-dash-mean-as-ffmpeg-output-filename)

Answer (score 7):

I don't have enough reputation to add a comment, so...

MrBar's example

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3  -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le pipe: | ffmpeg -f mp3 -i pipe: -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le encoded.mp3
```

should read,

```
ffmpeg -i file.mp3  -c:a pcm_s16le -f s16le pipe: | ffmpeg -f s16le -i pipe: -f mp3 encoded.mp3
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have to set the incoming stream's properties - and you may not feel like it - here's an alternative that I've used: use a fifo or a pipe (not the one mentioned above).

Here is an example using wget as a stream source, but cou can use anything, cat, nc, you name it:

```
$ mkfifo tmp.mp4 # or any other format
$ wget -O tmp.mp4 https://link.mp4 &
$ ffmpeg -i tmp.mp4 YourFileHere.mp4
```

Finally you may want to delete the pipe - you remove it like a normal file:

```
$ rm tmp.mp4
```

Voila!