# What does "dash" - mean as ffmpeg output filename

Tags: ffmpeg, parameters, spectrogram

I'm trying to use ffmpeg with gnuplot to draw some audio spectra, I'm following this [ffmpeg doc](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Waveform) link.

Now I'm asking what "dash" `-` means on this line right after `-f data`, it should be a filename: the last element of ffmpeg command should the output file but I have no files named `-` in the directory after running the command.

```
ffmpeg -y -i in.wav -ac 1 -filter:a aresample=8000 -map 0:a -c:a pcm_s16le -f data - | gnuplot -p -e "plot '<cat' binary filetype=bin format='%int16' endian=little array=1:0 with lines;"
```

I looked on ffmpeg docs but I didn't find anything.

Comment: On *nix it generally means the output will be written to stdout instead of a designated file name - this is consistent with the piped gnuplot command afterwards in your example.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`-` on the output side means `stdout`. You can also write `pipe:1` in its place. As input, it means `stdin` and can be written as `pipe:0`.

Comment: Is it documented anywhere that `pipe:` is the same as `-` BTW? Besides reading source ;-)

Comment: I had seen `pipe:` there and that it does the same as `-` usually does, but I didn't see an explicit mention of `-`. Just makes me think why both and if there's any difference.

Comment: `-` is checked for and treated as `pipe:0` or `pipe:1` depending on whether it's an input or output URL.