# Vimeo video - Auto Quality within HTML5 tag

Tags: video, video-streaming, html5-video, vimeo

I have a Vimeo Pro account which goes a little further than simply embedding a Vimeo file.

Instead, we are provided with a series of MP4 files (our video) which crucially allow us to use these in a HTML5 Video tag

**High def 1080 (mp4, 1920x1080)**
https://player.vimeo.com/external/1234.hd.mp4?s=4e75e5141ebd0acfd4ac6afad743e43af58c7770&profile_id=175

**High def (mp4, 1280x720)**
https://player.vimeo.com/external/1234.hd.mp4?s=4e75e5141ebd0acfd4ac6afad743e43af58c7770&profile_id=174

**Standard def (mp4, 960x540)**
https://player.vimeo.com/external/1234.sd.mp4?s=c2831c9383e9510d4e1120242fef4a2b0270e9b8&profile_id=165

**etc**

Ultimately, my HTML looks like this

```
<video style="display:none;" muted playsinline id="backgroundvid">
<source type="video/mp4" src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/1234.hd.mp4?s=4e75e5141ebd0acewrwerwerewr&profile_id=123">
</video>
```

The issue here is that specifying a hard-wired quality setting means our videos are devoid of adaptive bitrate settings.

Weirdly enough, a traditional Vimeo embed gets an AutoMode setting

> All videos on Vimeo default to Auto mode, which picks the best quality
> video for each viewer’s playback environment. Vimeo Plus, PRO, and
> Business members can default an embedded video to a specific quality
> by adding the quality parameter to the end of the player URL in the
> embed code.
>
> For example, if you want to default the embed to 1080p,
> you would add: https://player.vimeo.com/video/157588560?quality=1080p
>
> You can combine multiple URL parameters using an ampersand (&). For
> example:
> https://player.vimeo.com/video/157588560?autoplay=1&quality=1080p

Can anyone tell me how I use a direct MP4 link and set it to AutoMode?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the direct mp4 links, Vimeo also provides [HLS](https://developer.apple.com/streaming/) links for adaptive video quality playback.

You can find the HLS link in the same section where the direct mp4 links can be found (look for "HTTP Live Streaming").

Take a look at Vimeo's direct video file link docs here: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224823567-Third-party-player-links

Comment: Hi Tommy. I did see a direct link to a HTTP live streaming link. However when I add this to my html 5 source it returns no video.

Comment: Take a look at this SO query about using HLS links (.m3u8 files) with the HTML video tag (note that it's a few years old, so you may want to seek out more recent answers or other resources): https://stackoverflow.com/q/19782389/3704546