# I can not play video with m3u8 format

Tags: android, react-native, exoplayer, react-native-video

I am building a project in React Native and I used the react-native-video dependency to play video streaming, but it does not play anything when the file is m3u8. Will it be the file codec?

Video playback is successful in other formats, but entering this url does not work.

This is my configuration in the Video component:

Version: 4.3.1

```
<Video source={{uri: 
"https://s3.amazonaws.com/yojma/hls/movie/yvZmxnCwaHGSLUpKFzoTlYrOXRdWQgePIqihbfcs/main.m3u8", 
type:"m3u8"} }/>
```

And this in app/build.gradle:

```
dependencies { compile project(':react-native-video-exoplayer') 
implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+" // From node_modules 
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"]) implementation 
"com.android.support:appcompat-v7:${rootProject.ext.supportLibVersion}" 
}
```

And this settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'Yojma' include ':react-native-video-exoplayer' 
project(':react-native-video-exoplayer').projectDir = new 
File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native- 
video/android-exoplayer') include ':app'
```

Comment: Check
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782389/playing-m3u8-files-with-html-video-tag You need HLS library to play streams in video.

Comment: Is this also true in React Native? I have not read something like that in the documentation.

Comment: it is how web is working. There is probably a package for that in react native.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/issues/522#issuecomment-291015622

Comment: Hi. I've done that step, you can check it in the code I've put.

Comment: Hey did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score -5):

Some work and others not for example I use this and it works for me

```
         <Video
            source={{ uri: 'http://qthttp.apple.com.edgesuite.net/1010qwoeiuryfg/sl.m3u8' }}
            rate={1.0}
            volume={1.0}
            isMuted={false}
            resizeMode="cover"
            shouldPlay={false}
            useNativeControls={true}
            isLooping
            style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}
          />
        </View>
```

Comment: this is not an answer to the question asked. Please consider removing it. You can add this as a comment.