# How to embed a m3u8 stream

Tags: m3u8

is it possible to embed an m3u8 stream?
i tried several players and stuff but it just don't play, is it something about crossdomain?

here is what i got

https://html.house/f16jzx1y.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Playing m3u8 Files with HTML Video Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782389/playing-m3u8-files-with-html-video-tag)

Comment: some streams work, some others wont, i guess some of them are domain protected? because i can watch it on VLC no problems

Answer (score 0):

You must configure CORS server side. If you do not control the server, then it’s not possible to embedded the stream in another domain. That is exactly the purpose of CORS.

Comment: thats what i tought.
Thanks!