# Playing m3u8 video in React

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an url which is in m3u8 format from the backend in my project. How to play m3u8 format in react.. I am using React player package and it does not seem to be supporting it. Is there any other way to display m3u8 format? I found ReactHlsPlayer.. I could not display using that as well
Thank you

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782389/playing-m3u8-files-with-html-video-tag

Answer (score 0):

Use Vime Player it supports HLS and many more file type playing and also supports many js library including React