# Autoplay for... Playing m3u8 Files with HTML Video Tag

Tags: html, video, playback, autoplay

can you help me... if I use code below, from question: [Playing m3u8 Files with HTML Video Tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782389/playing-m3u8-files-with-html-video-tag/62573839#62573839)

How can I set AUTOPLAY ? Load and play stream, straight just after load a page?

### Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Your title</title>
      
    
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
      <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
      data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="https://cdn3.wowza.com/1/ejBGVnFIOW9yNlZv/cithRSsv/hls/live/playlist.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      </video>
      
    <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
    player.play();
    </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

---

Kind Regards
Tomas

Comment: Autoplay isn't recommended, and autoplay for non-muted video actively blocked. https://developer.chrome.com/blog/autoplay/