# Play .m3u8 video in the react native video

Tags: react-native, m3u8, react-native-video

I am playing HLS streaming in the react native using react-native-video and it is working fine. And I want to know that can I play .m3u8 video from Local storage of mobile. Like I have downloaded m3u8 stream in the mobile storage and then I want to play it from the app. So how can I play it. Please let me know if there is anyway to play it from mobile storage in react-native-video.

Also I want to know if there is any good way to download m3u8 streaming in the mobile.

Comment: seems like a duplicate to me (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782389/playing-m3u8-files-with-html-video-tag).. either way - you need to use an external module in order to support this feature (as `m3u8` format is not natively supported by browsers)

Comment: @ymz it's not a duplicate at all. This question is specifically about React Native and the react-native-video package and the linked question is about vanilla HTML.

Comment: @Rover Can you help with hls streaming with react-native-video

Comment: Hey @Rover, this is totally unrelated to your question, but yeah, I'm relatively new to React native development, I see you mentioned you were able to play videos using react-native-video using HLS protocol, just wanted to know how we can achieve it since there are less resourses for it, let's say my videos are in firebase storage, how can I implement HLS to stream them in my React native app? We can connect in any other platform and discuss if you are okay with it

Answer (score -1):

OK... so:

The original answer suggested to use [this library](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-hls) in order to support `HLS videos`

It's easy to see that this library is at the end of its life and will be deprecated and replaced soon by a [newer library](https://github.com/videojs/http-streaming)

When I wrote in my comment that this question is **seems like a duplicate**, I meant that the solution suggested is framework-agnostic (e.g. - it's supports all frameworks that let you include external `JS module` which is practically all platforms). That is also why I didn't mark this question as duplicate, despite the similarity.

**In short:** you may use this solution in your project and probably end up with a little react component for a video element to wrap all logic in a single re-usable unit. To get this right - I suggest you take a look at [video.js react guidelines](https://videojs.com/guides/react/) and use the sample provided there as a base to your component

Happy development ya all!