# How to add javascript popup on load

Tags: javascript, html, video-streaming, html5-video

Javascript Popup sample on page load, you can set timer also

```
    // alert('update')
    if (confirm("Popup Shown here") == true) {
    window.open("https://example.com/", '_blank');
}
```

Comment: <video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="https://webudi.openhd.lol/ddy1/premium32/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8|referer=https://streamservicehd.click/" type="video/mp4">

  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>  this is actual file

Comment: Please add a `type`-attribute to the `source` tag and check if it solves your issue.

Comment: You need to check the same place where you got that M3U8 . Is there a player there? When video is playing, you need to check what is the URL of the TS files and finally edit the M3U8 to include that path for each TS file.

Comment: I found this link in encrypted php embed page it works only when i pass referer in network streamer app, bt won't work in any webplayer

Comment: @Sarc Check by using the Developer Tools of your browser. You need to find the correct path of a TS file. Right now the M3U8 says the path of the TS is: `https://webudi.openhd.lol/ddy1/premium32/tracks-v1a1/` but that one is not correct. So just check where the TS file **really comes from** (I think it re-directs)... **(2)** Most likely you have to edit the M3U8 afterwards to include the correct path (you edit in PHP or Javascript) if you want to play the video.

Answer (score 2):

This is because mono.m3u8 is not a video file except it contains a link to different files (playlist/audio/video). You can learn more about [m3u8 here](https://docs.fileformat.com/audio/m3u8/). Want to know more about [valid video extensions](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) that are accepted in HTML. They are basically only 3 of them: `MP4`, `WebM`, and `OGG`.

Comment: I manage everything but i got stuck in referer

Comment: what do you mean by that? Can you elaborate a little?

Comment: I am looking for webplayer to play this link  https://webudi.openhd.lol/ddy1/premium32/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?http-referer=https://streamservicehd.click/  this link playable in network streamer app but wont in web player

Comment: can you make sure that your provided link works? because for me it isn't, even in VLC media player

Comment: I don't know whether it's a problem with your link or is it restricted link but it isn't working for me in any case. I tried using different decoding services and players but nothing was able to play it.

Answer (score 1):

Even `m3u8` is not supported directly by HTML. You can play it using some external libraries that are built specifically for playing these type of files.
In my case it is [HLS.js](https://github.com/video-dev/hls.js/).

You can also reffer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782389/playing-m3u8-files-with-html-video-tag) as I think this could also help.

### Code

```
<html>

<body>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/hls.js@latest"></script> <video id="video" controls>
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
  </video>
  <script> if (Hls.isSupported()) {
      var video = document.getElementById('video');
      var hls = new His();
      hls.loadSource('https://webudi.openhd.lol/ddy1/premium32/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?http-referer=https://streamservicehd.click/');
      hls.attachMedia(video);
      hls.on(Hls.Events.MANIFEST_PARSED, function () {
        video.play();
      });
    } else if (video.canPlayType('application/vnd.apple.mpegurl')) {
      video.src = 'https://webudi.openhd.lol/ddy1/premium32/tracks-v1a1/mono.m3u8?http-referer=https://streamservicehd.click/';
      video.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
        video.play();
      });
    } 
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

#### Note

I can not make sure it worked or not as the file you provided is not working for me in any case.

Comment: It on works with referer i think it can be done by php